# pythonモジュールの最新バージョンをインストールせずにコマンドラインで確認する方法

Tags: python

pythonモジュールがインストールされている/いないに関わらず、コマンドラインでモジュールの最新バージョンを出力させる方法はあるでしょうか。

イメージとしてはyum info [package_name]でAvailable Packagesが取得できるのと同じようにできればと思っています。

Comment: 現時点ではできないのであくまでコメント欄ですが、https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1415にてpip search内に最新バージョンを表示するPRがありますので、近いうちに使えるようになるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。pipの6系リリースがちょうど1ヶ月前(2014-12-22)です。これまでのメジャーアップデートのスパンを考えると、2015年中に来るかどうかという感じですね。

Answer (score 2):

pipにはそのようなオプションは無さそうです。

思いつく代替案は `easy_install -n django` のようにdry-runでインストールすることですが、パッケージのダウンロードまで実行してしまいます。

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/json から情報を取得して表示するスクリプトを作るのが楽そうです。

info.py:

```
import urllib
import sys
import json
uo = urllib.urlopen('https://pypi.python.org/pypi/%s/json' % sys.argv[1])
pkg = json.load(uo)
print pkg['info']['version']
```

$ python2.7 info.py django
1.8a1

Answer (score 2):

本家にも同じような質問/回答があったので共有します。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available

ここで紹介されている[yolk](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yolk/0.4.3)というツールが良さそうな感じでした。pypiで利用可能なすべてのバージョンを表示してくれるようです。

```
$ yolk -V sphinx
Sphinx 1.3b3
Sphinx 1.2.3
```